# How much Weight can a drywall ceiling hold

Tags: ceiling

I want to hang something and I want to make sure it doesn’t fall

Comment: Do not recommend hanging anything from drywall ceiling. What are you wanting to hang?

Comment: I wouldn't do anything more than a few oz. Your adhesive should fail before the drywall does.

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to not hang anything just from the ceiling drywall by itself. Particularly anything you have concern that it could fall due to its weight or safety of people or things under the hanging object.

Instead you need to locate the structure that holds the drywall in place and screw the hooks / brackets / retainers into that structure. The type of things you screw in would be dependent upon whether the ceiling structure was wood, metal rails or concrete. But since we have no guidance from you yet as to what type of structure you have suggestions are limited.

Comment: I have pinned Acuity lighting sensors into drywall ceilings, that being said, if they fell on someone, it is unlikely a serious injury would occur as they are plastic and lightweight.   It would not surprise me if the OP intended to hang something heavy enough (ceiling fan etc.) that could seriously injure someone.